# Combine 'check information(s)' in a loop php

Tags: php, loops

I require to combine a check information together in a loop but face errors. A single check info is fine (refer to the following set codes).

First off: this checks the various check info:

1. $checkGeneral
2. $checkProduct

   ```
   foreach($resultCatAdd as &$value) {
       if($value == "General Information") {
           $checkGeneral = true;
       } elseif ($value == "Product Information") {
           $checkProduct = true;
       } 
   }
   ```

Here i call the main SQL which i'll need to execute:

```
$SQL = "SELECT *
        FROM einv_asset 
        WHERE einv_asset_stockrm  = '" . $code . "';
";
```

This coding is to check if info is true or false(direct to another function) and perform an add function

```
$get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($SQL);
    while($General_row = base_fetch_array($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL))

    if (base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL)!= 0)
    {

        // General Information category
        if ($checkGeneral == true) {

            if(einv_editStockrm2($General_row['einv_asset_code'],"General"))
            {   
                $addGeneralSQL="INSERT INTO einv_general_information (einv_ginfo_status,einv_ginfo_remark,einv_ginfo_aid)
                    VALUES ('" . $status . "','" . base_addSlashSQL($remark) . "','" . $General_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

                //echo $getGeneralSQL;

                //Check and execute query
                if(!base_executeSQL($addGeneralSQL)) {
                    $continue = false;
                    echo $addGeneralSQL;
                }else { $continue = true; }
            }
        }
```

It will then lead to a second function when check info is false

function2:

```
if($category == "General")
    {
        $generalSQL = "SELECT * FROM einv_general_information WHERE einv_ginfo_aid = '" . $assetcode . "') ";
        $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($generalSQL);
        $total = base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL);
        if ($total!= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($total== 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The codes above works fine but there's error as I try to include in `$checkProduct` together with the `$checkGeneral` as above

(consider EVERYTHING is similar except that **general** is to change to **product**)

Here is how i added:

```
$get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($SQL);
    while($General_row = base_fetch_array($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL))

    if (base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL)!= 0)
    {

        // General Information category
        if ($checkGeneral == true) {

            if(einv_editStockrm2($General_row['einv_asset_code'],"General"))
            {   
                $addGeneralSQL="INSERT INTO einv_general_information (einv_ginfo_status,einv_ginfo_remark,einv_ginfo_aid)
                    VALUES ('" . $status . "','" . base_addSlashSQL($remark) . "','" . $General_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

                //echo $getGeneralSQL;

                //Check and execute query
                if(!base_executeSQL($addGeneralSQL)) {
                    $continue = false;
                    echo $addGeneralSQL;
                }else { $continue = true; }
            }
        } 
        $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($SQL);
        while($Product_row = base_fetch_array($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL))
        if (base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL)!= 0)
        if ($checkProduct == true) {

            if(einv_editStockrm2($Product_row['einv_asset_code'],"Product"))
            {
                $addProductSQL="INSERT INTO einv_product_information (einv_pinfo_pn,einv_pinfo_serial,einv_pinfo_desc,einv_pinfo_itemcat,einv_pinfo_aid)
        VALUES ('" . $partno . "','" . $serial . "','" . base_addSlashSQL($desc) . "','" . $itemcatID . "','" . $Product_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

            if(!base_executeSQL($addProductSQL)){
                $continue = false;
                echo $addProductSQL;
            }else { $continue = true; }
            }
        }
```

And in function 2:

```
if($category == "General")
    {
        $generalSQL = "SELECT * FROM einv_general_information WHERE einv_ginfo_aid = '" . $assetcode . "') ";
        $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($generalSQL);
        $total = base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL);
        if ($total!= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($total== 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if($category == "Product")
    {
        $productSQL ="SELECT * FROM einv_product_information WHERE einv_pinfo_aid = '" . $assetcode . "') ";
        $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($productSQL);
        $total = base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL);
        if ($total!= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($total== 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How do i amend my codes to allow this two checks to work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't go fully to your explanation. Still i think i have a reason to answer.

**Steps:**

1. Create `Switch Case`, rather than conditions `if-else`, to check conditions true.
2. Execute function as per your need.

I think,  the simple and the best solution to this question starts from switch case.